# MySql Procedure For Bonus Calculation Updating the Entire Table

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, cursor

Trying to write a simple procedure in mysql to calculate the bonus based on department id. The following is what i am doing. The problem is when i give my procedure a particular department id, it updates the salary for the entire table with the same salary value and not restrict itself to the provided dept id. Spent a lot of time on it but couldn't manage to figure out the issue.

```
create table employees(emp_id integer,dept_id int(4),emp_name varchar(10), salary float(11));
alter table employees add primary key (emp_id);
insert into employees values(1, 1,'A1',30);
insert into employees values(2, 2,'R1', 40);
insert into employees values(3, 3,'A2', 50);
insert into employees values(4, 4,'S1', 60);
insert into employees values(5, 1,'A3', 700);


delimiter $$
create procedure calculate_bonus(in in_dept_id int)
begin
declare done int default false;
declare emp_id integer;
declare dept_id int(4);
declare emp_name varchar(10); 
declare new_salary float(11);
declare hike float(11);
declare c1 cursor for
select * from employees;
Declare continue handler for not found set done = TRUE;

open c1;
read_cursor: LOOP
fetch c1 into emp_id, dept_id, emp_name, new_salary;
if done then
leave read_cursor;
end if;


if(dept_id = in_dept_id) then
select case dept_id
when 1 then 10
when 2 then 20
when 3 then 30
else 40
end
into hike;

set new_salary = new_salary + (new_salary*hike/100);
select concat("salary",new_salary);

update employees
set salary = new_salary where dept_id = in_dept_id;
select concat("dept_id",dept_id, in_dept_id);
end if;
end LOOP read_cursor;
close c1;
end
$$

call calculate_bonus(3);
select * from employees;
```

---

The output I am getting is:

```
salary65
dept_id33
1   1   A1  65
2   2   R1  65
3   3   A2  65
4   4   S1  65
5   1   A2  65
```

Comment: Does it make sense do you think to select all employees into your cursor if you are only interested in dept_id = 3 and does it make sense to update all employees for dept_id evrey time through the cursor loop?Also don't give parameters and declared variables the same names as column names.

Comment: @P.Salmon: Thanks for the input.

As per your first suggestion, I have changed my select statement to: 
declare c1 cursor for
select * from employees where dept_id=in_dept_id;

now it is not updating any of the records.

As per my understanding I am writing the cursor to fetch all the records with the matching dept id and update the salary for each of them. Hence the use of cursor. My idea is to hold all the matching dept id in the cursor. I am more interested in knowing what is going wrong in the current logic.

Comment: @P.Salmon your idea of separating the variable name from the column name seems to be one of the main culprits but now, records with same dept id are getting updated with the incremented salary of the last record for that dept id. e.g.

1 1 A1 770 , 

2 2 R1 40,

3 3 A2 50,

4 4 S1 60,

5 1 A3 770,

Initial salary of A1 was 30 but now it is getting updated with the incremented salary of A3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t(emp_id integer,dept_id int(4),emp_name varchar(10), salary float(11));
alter table t add primary key (emp_id);
insert into t values(1, 1,'A1',30);
insert into t values(2, 2,'R1', 40);
insert into t values(3, 3,'A2', 50);
insert into t values(4, 4,'S1', 60);
insert into t values(5, 1,'A3', 700);

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$

create procedure p(in in_dept_id int)
begin
declare done int default false;
declare vemp_id integer;
declare vdept_id int(4);
declare vemp_name varchar(10); 
declare vnew_salary float(11);
declare vhike float(11);
declare c1 cursor for select * from t where dept_id = in_dept_id;
Declare continue handler for not found set done = TRUE;

open c1;
read_cursor: LOOP
fetch c1 into vemp_id, vdept_id, vemp_name, vnew_salary;
if done then
    leave read_cursor;
end if;


select case vdept_id
    when 1 then 10
    when 2 then 20
    when 3 then 30
    else 40
    end
    into vhike;

    set vnew_salary = vnew_salary + (vnew_salary*vhike/100);
    select concat("salary",vnew_salary);

    update t
        set salary = vnew_salary where dept_id = in_dept_id;
    select concat("dept_id",vdept_id, in_dept_id);


end LOOP read_cursor;
close c1;
end $$

call p(3);
call p(1);
select * from t;

+--------+---------+----------+--------+
| emp_id | dept_id | emp_name | salary |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
|      1 |       1 | A1       |     33 |
|      2 |       2 | R1       |     40 |
|      3 |       3 | A2       |     65 |
|      4 |       4 | S1       |     60 |
|      5 |       1 | A3       |    770 |
+--------+---------+----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note I have uniquely named the declared variables, amended the cursor select to only select the dept_id I am interested in,removed the now redundant if statement and further qualified the update statement on employee id.
The procedure (possibly) and the cursor (definitely) are unnecessary (unless you have been specifically told to do it this way) and the same result can be achieved by a single update statement for example

```
update t
    set salary = salary + (salary * case dept_id
            when 1 then 10
            when 2 then 20
            when 3 then 30
            else 40
            end / 100)
        where dept_id = 3;
```

With a simple change to accept a parameter value instead of the hard coded 3 this would be all the code you would need in your procedure.